# Who is this woman called Hikari?

Tags: sasurai-emanon

I've read this manga called **Sasurai Emanon** (a.k.a. Emanon's Wanderings) about a girl who possesses all her ancestors' memories.

In some of the first few chapters a characters called Hikari made her appearance: she seems to be an acquaintance of the main character, but at a certain point (Chapter 7) there is this conversation:

[image: pic1]

[image: pic2]

It suggest that Hikari is some sort of time traveler, but it has never been explained and after this moment the character never appears in the story again.

The story seems to follow some series of novels: does the author explain something more about this character in these novels (or somewhere else)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hikari also appears in author's other work: *Omoide Emanon* (or *Memories of Emanon*), a collection of short stories (not the manga version, which only tells about chapter *Omoide Emanon*, not the rest). In fact, she appeared for the first time there.

She appears in chapter ***Ashibiki Daydream***, which takes place in 1994. [The synopsis by a Japanese reader](http://hitter7777.blog.fc2.com/blog-entry-672.html) *(you can skip this and read the next spoiler block for Hikari's identity directly)*:

> Year 1994. There's a girl who suddenly appeared in front of Akira's room. After some time, they were living together in Akira's place. One day, Akira saw a girl who seems to be in same generation with Hikari. Her name was Emanon. After some days relying and be relied upon her, Hikari disappeared in front of Akira. Her traces of living in Akira's place also disappeared totally. When Akira was walking alone through a street back in 6-year university period, Akira realized there's no one who could remember Hikari. When Akira visited her hometown in a mountainous village, Akira met Emanon.

From another [short review by Japanese reader](http://michi.ciao.jp/jikan/timebj1.html):

> [...] Emanon told Akira about Hikari's secret. **Hikari was a girl who had power to time-leap**. Emanon have met her up to 1.2 trillion years ago.